# Check if String is null from a Class

Tags: java, android

i know that my question is a duplicate of some question here before,  i tried every solution that i see from that, but no solution work for me

i have a class named FilingModel and a method name getReason, i always get a null value to my tvReason TextView

```
public class FilingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilingAdapter.FilingHolder> {
  List<FilingModel> lists;
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FilingHolder holder, int position) {
     FilingModel model = lists.get(position);
     holder.tvReason.setText(model.getReason());
   }

}
```

```
public class FilingModel {

    private String reason;

    public FilingModel(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        if ( reason.isEmpty() || TextUtils.isEmpty(reason) || reason.equals(null)) {
           reason = "-";
        }
        return reason;
    }
}
```

Comment: `reason.equals(null)` will throw NullPointerException if `reason` is null. It should be `reason == null`

Comment: You could just initialize `reason` with `"-"`, like `private String reason = "-";`. That way, it won't become `null` until it is explicitly set to...

Comment: i also tried that solution still not work

Comment: Also `reason==null` needs to be checked before `reason.isEmpty()`.

Comment: can you show the scenario, how do you use it, so you always get null ?

Comment: @P.Juni i'm using it to my RecycleView Adapter, to setText my, TextView tvReason

Comment: show the code please

Comment: the null check should also be the very first thing to check

Comment: @P.Juni i updated it :)

Comment: @deHaar i tried but still not working

Comment: In this case you might want to check if your list is properly initialised. Though I concur with @deHaar, setting the `reason` to `-` by default will not only make sure that you have the default value to fall back to, but also clean up your getter method (it's better to have simple getter and setters without any business logic)

Comment: @Eran still won't work, i tried using your solution

Answer (score 0):

String checks for null are rather straight forward (once you have done it):

First you want to check if the instance is `null` (otherwise all further manipulation might fail):

```
 if(reason == null)
```

Then you want to check if it is `empty` as you already did it but maybe you want to trim it first (to remove all whitespaces):

```
if(reason == null || reason.trim().isEmpty())
```

as you can see you can chain the conditions with `or` since Java will stop evaluating the conditions once one of them was found `true` . So if your string is `null`, Java will not evaluate if it is empty.

And that's all you need, `null` and `isEmpty` (and optionally with a `trim()`)

```
public String getReason() {
    if(reason==null || reason.trim().isEmpty()){
       reason = "-";
    }
    return reason;
}
```

Comment: i tried it, but it still not working for me

Comment: FYI, the short version (without trim) is simply `if(reason == null || reason.isEmpty())` no need for `TextUtils` or other external tools. Just keep in mind that you first check for null before you check anything else.

Comment: what exactly is not working? are you getting an Exception or is the result different from what you expect?

Comment: @GameDriods i don't get any exception

Answer (score -1):

Give type to your variable reason. For example String.

```
private String reason;
```

+

```
if(reason == null)
```

Comment: first need to check null otherwise null pointer exception

Comment: Thank you i have it already,